# Tuition fees vs enrolment fees?

Tags: fees, tuition

What is the difference between tuition fees and enrolment fees? The University I'm planning to apply for MA studies, requires Non-EU students to pay 1500 euros per semester for tuition and 150 euros per semester for enrolment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in Germany, the difference is that everybody (including locals) has to pay enrollment fees. Those are fees that cover some administrative costs and also often include the compulsory purchase of a semester ticket for public transport and money used to subsidize the student canteen. Tuition fees actually cover some of the costs for teaching you.

All *Bundesländer*, except Baden-Württemberg [which charges 1500 €](https://mwk.baden-wuerttemberg.de/de/hochschulen-studium/studienfinanzierung/gebuehren-fuer-internationale-studierende-und-zweitstudium/tuition-fees-for-international-students/) from international students, have abolished tuition fees for undergrad studies and many for grad studies.

References:

http://www.internationale-studierende.de/en/prepare_your_studies/financing/cost_of_education/

Answer (score 1):

Tuition fees are the cost of the degree you want to study. The enrollment fee is just the amount of money you have to pay to enroll yourself into that course.